# LoadError (Unable to autoload constant XYZ, expected XYZ.rb to define it) in development environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rack

Recently, I can't make changes to my app without restarting my development server, otherwise I receive this error:

```
LoadError (Unable to autoload constant BotFeedback, expected ../../bot_feedback.rb to define it)
```

This hasn't been a problem before and I'm not entirely sure why this has become a problem. I have these settings configured in application.rb:

```
# Auto-load the bot and its subdirectories
config.paths.add File.join('app', 'bot'), glob: File.join('**', '*.rb')
config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'bot', '*')]
```

My app/bot folder includes files such as:

bot.rb with:

```
require "#{Rails.root}/app/bot/orderbot.rb"
Bot.on :message do |message|
  OrderBot.new()
  ..
end

def somefunction
  OrderBot.new()
  ..
end
```

orderbot.rb with:

```
require "#{Rails.root}/app/bot/bot_feedback.rb"
require "#{Rails.root}/app/bot/bot_demo.rb"
require "#{Rails.root}/app/bot/bot_helper.rb"
class OrderBot
  include BotFeedback
  include BotDemo
  include BotHelper
  (many more includes)
  ..
end
```

bot_feedback.rb with:

```
require "#{Rails.root}/app/models/concerns/sharedmethods.rb"
class OrderBot
  include Sharedmethods
  module BotFeedback
    ...
  end
end
```

bot_demo.rb with:

```
class OrderBot
  module BotDemo
    ..
  end
end
```

bot_helper.rb with:

```
require "#{Rails.root}/app/models/concerns/sharedmethods.rb"
class OrderBot
  include Sharedmethods
  module BotHelper
    ...
  end
end
```

My guess is that including the sharedmethods file is causing this because I don't see anything else being a problem. Changing the sharedmethods file in the rails app has always seemed to require restarting the server.

I would appreciate any help/suggestions.

UPDATE:

Looks like using 'load' instead of 'require' seems to solve the problem. I'm not sure this is the right way to go about it though.. because it will take up more memory if the files are being loaded again and again?

```
load "#{Rails.root}/app/bot/bot_feedback.rb"
load "#{Rails.root}/app/bot/bot_demo.rb"
load "#{Rails.root}/app/bot/bot_helper.rb"
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured out the answer after learning everything about rails 'autoload' and 'require'

I don't actually need to 'require' any of the files because they are already autoloaded. The culprit was the 'module', it wasn't necessary.